# Migration from Webpack 3.x to 4.x

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need help on migration of widgets-like product from Webpack 3.x to 4.x. I've stuck due to removal of CommonsChunkPlugin and now I can't achieve the same behavior using SplitChunksPlugin.

[Here](https://github.com/tpolovyi/widgets-webpack-demo) is a repo with a small demo to show the problem. Is there any way to achieve the same code splitting using Webpack 4.x.

UPD: The goal is to keep common modules in loader entry bundle, everything else should reuse them. Please, check out webpack-4 branch, maybe I'm missing something there.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Because here, it generated loader, widget1, widget2, when updated to webpack 4. The same result as webpack 3.

Comment: Not exactly. Files set remains the same, but with webpack 4.x each entry has it's own instance of common modules, and my goal is to keep common things in `loader.js` and reuse them by other entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I came to the solution by myself.

In Webpack 4 there's no way to put the common modules into one of the entries, so the only way is to put them into common.js (of course, if there is a big common bundle, it makes sense to split it into several smaller ones and to load them only when needed).

```
splitChunks: {
  chunks: 'all'
  name: 'common',
  minChunks: 2,
},
```

Then, in order to make the loader executable without common.js, it should be ignored by splitChunks:

```
splitChunks: {
  chunks: chunk => chunk.name !== 'loader',
  name: 'common',
  minChunks: 2,
},
```

As a result from loader code other entries can be loaded alongside with commons

```
Promise.all([
  loadCommon(),
  loadEntry(),
]).then(() => runEntry());
```

Sorry for the silly question, the solution turned out to be on a surface.